# Django Braintree : KeyError at /payments-billing/

Tags: django, braintree

I am trying to implement [django-braintree](https://github.com/Tivix/django-braintree) for my django-oscar project. I installed the django-braintree app and added my details in settings.py. I got a credit card details page(`/payment-details`). I add `/pay` url for a simple form. But when I am submitting it `KeyError expiration_month at /payments-billing/` is coming. How do I send it to the server ?

My server side:

```
braintree.Configuration.configure(
    braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
    "****",
    "****",
    "****"
)

def client_token():
  return braintree.ClientToken.generate()

def create_purchase(request):
  nonce = request.form["payment_method_nonce"]

result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
    "amount": "1000.00",
    "credit_card": {
        "number": "4111111111111111",
        "expiration_date": "05/2020"
    }
})

def pay(request):
    try:
        resp_dict = {}
        resp_dict["client_token"] = client_token()
        resp_dict["result"] = result
    except Exception as e:
        resp_dict["error"] = e
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'django_braintree/pay_new.html', resp_dict)
```

My HTML:

```
{% block layout %}

  <form id="checkout" method="post" action="/payments-billing/">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div id="payment-form"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>

<script>
  braintree.setup(
    // Replace this with a client token from your server
    "{{ client_token }}",
    "dropin", {
      container: "payment-form"
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The third-party django-braintree library is not currently compatible with the Braintree Drop-In. The Drop-In only supports `expiration_date` while the form in the library expects `expiration_month` and `expiration_year`, causing the KeyError you're getting. This library has also not been updated to use payment method nonces. I would not recommend using this library, but instead write your own django integration to Braintree using our [Python client library](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/start/overview).